# Circle Theorem Problem

Tags: calculus

I was working on some problems, and eventually I ran into this one. I've given it some thought but can't seem to approach a reasonable answer. Since this is just practice an explanation is more valued than an answer. Thanks for any help!
[image]

Comment: calculate the angle $LON$ and express it as a fraction of $360$ degrees. then take this fraction of the given circumference

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin with the property that a circle's radius is perpendicular to that tangent.

We thus have $\angle ONM = \angle OLM=90º$.

Therefore, since in a quadrilateral (specifically OLMN), that the angles add up to $360º$, we have $\angle LON=360º-90º-90º-60º=120º$.

Therefore, the angle of the minor arc is equal to the length of the central angle, or $120º$.

Since the circumference of the circle is $96$, we have the arc length is $\displaystyle \frac{120}{360} * 96 = \boxed{32}$.

Answer (score 1):

Find the angle $LON$ can be deduced using the fact that $OLM$ and $ONM$ are $\pi/2$ degrees. Then $(LON/2 \pi) \cdot 96 $ will give the answer.